# Is it necessary to be completely still during body scan?

Tags: meditation

I've been practising vipassana for some time. Now, I'd like to try body scan, but one issue isn't clear for me. Books or articles about sitting meditation, I've read, say that it's good to sit completely still during practise. Does the same implay to body scan? Should I lie entirely still during body scan or can I move my hand, for example, when I feel such a need?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are things to learn by not moving but i doubt it is essential since it is nowhere mentioned in the Sutta afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that its necessary, but its for the purpose of noticing the body sensations as they occur naturally. Moving would create a sensation and possibly the desire to create or cease a particular sensation.  If you find difficulty in staying still maybe try mindfulness walking, and/or observances of daily activities

Answer (score 0):

> **I've read, say that it's good to sit completely still during practise. Does the same implay to body scan?**

Yes. Ideally.

If it is difficult you can take the liberty to move. But staying still:

- increases your [Adhiṭṭhāna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhi%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na) - This is why in courses at least for 3 of the 1-hour sessions you are asked to stay still in courses taught by Goenka
- increases your Samadhi